# How to post to salesforce web to lead using express.router()

Tags: node.js, express, salesforce

I'm new to node.js, I have a salesforce web to lead form. I want to use express.Router() to post the form to salesforce. How do i format the

```
router.post( '/Contact', function(req,res,next) {
 var body = req.body;
});
```

body? The form action = 'https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8' 
and for example the OID = '1111111' ** I will use process.env.ORG_ID to get the real org ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express isn't used for making a request but rather is a library for making Web APIs/Apps. If you need to make a request then you could use [request](https://github.com/request/request) which is very popular and wraps the Node Core API HTTP Library function, [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Using `request` you can make your POST request to salesforce as such

```
let orgId = process.env.ORG_ID
request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://webto.saleforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8&OID=${orgid}`
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    return err
  }

  // Handle res/body per needs
})
```